# ESP32 sourcing 20 times 5 mA?

Tags: power, current, esp32, source

I want to drive 20 optotriacs (MOC3063, each requiring 5 mA from the control side for the diodes in the optos).

I want a 3.3 V ESP32 nodemcu board (wifi enabled as acces point) to control them.

These optos and resistors represent the entirety of electronics, drawing 100 mA (20*5 mA).

besides the opto, only the MCU sinks current, and I plan to drive it directly from a 3.3 V switched power supply.

I searched and found that any single pin can source 40 mA but that is not the point.

I read from [this post](https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=5840#p71756) that there are different power domain with different source current, but I do not fully understand it.

So i wonder if I could drive the twenty MOC3063 directly from GPIO and resistors.

Or if I am indeed forced to drive the chips using some middleman IC, like a 74hc595 extender, or uln2003 (way overkill, current wise).

So, do you think I can reduce my BOM and drive the optos directly or not?

Answer (score 2):

The Espressif site has a number of datasheets on their line of chips. The [ESP32 series datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf) indicates that the total I/O output current must not exceed 1200 mA. I believe your 100 mA will not be a problem.

[image: image description]